# Computer PSU 5v Output direct with Raspberry Pi USB

Tags: power-supply, power, raspberry-pi

I'm using an old power supply unit from an old computer (2011 HIPRO) to power my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B V1.1 (2014).

I have measured the voltage across the terminals of the 5v output (Red and Black) and have proceeded to hook this up to a USB adapter which goes straight to the Pi.

My problem is that using this PSU the red "on" indicator light does not turn on, versus when I use a USB charger it does.

Was there a problem with this red light not turning on? Is this bad for the Pi?

BTW everything works fine using both power supplies, the Pi turns on and the screen is shown, able to login etc.

Please see my photo of my setup below:

[image: one]

Closer View of the PSU pin outs:

[image: two]

Comment: solderless breadboard is not well suited to the 500mA (aoorox) load that the raspberry PI presents,

Answer (score 1):

Your five volt power isn't really five volts.  The newer Pis will run but turn off the LED if the power in drops below 4.63 volts.

Check the 5Volts where it connects to the Pi.  You may have losses in the wires from the power supply, and the power supply itself may just put out a slightly low voltage on the 5Volt rail.  Given the way you have things wired (multiple plugs and jacks and a breadboard in the middle,) it isn't just MAY have losses, it is rather WILL have losses.  (Thanks to @pipe for pointing it out.)

[Info from here.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24664/what-do-the-leds-on-the-b-mean/24674#24674)  There are links in that post that lead to more info.

Comment: With the setup in the picture, you _will_ have losses, not _may_ have. :)

Answer (score 0):

Red light off on a modern Pi (B+ or newer) indicates undervoltage, this won't damage the Pi but may well cause reliability problems.

You need to go through the circuit with your multimeter measuring the voltage at each stage (including at the test points or GPIO header on the Pi) and find the cause of the low voltage. My guess is that the wires in the USB cable you are using are too thin

Answer (score 0):

As @JRE mentions you have losses on the wires. Instead of connecting to the 20/24 (can't see in the photo) pin header, use **several** of the black and red lines in the ATA (or SATA) power lines, probably soldering them together.

Using a similar methods I used and old PC PSU to power a LED tape with 6A@12V with no problems.